# Reset module in unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, qunit

I have a requirejs module created with the following pattern:

```
// foo.js
define(function(){

    var x = 0;

    function doStuff(){
        return ++x;
    }

    return { doStuff: doStuff };

});
```

And a QUnit test which looks something like this:

```
// testfoo.js
define(['QUnit, foo'], function(QUnit, foo){

    function setup(){
        //...?
    }        

    function teardown(){
       //...?
    }

    function runTests(){

         QUnit.test('foo counter remains at 1 on multiple tests', function(assert){
              assert.equal(foo.doStuff(), 1); // this will work
         });

         QUnit.test('foo counter remains at 1 on multiple tests', function(assert){
              assert.equal(foo.doStuff(), 1); // this obviously won't
         });
     }

     return runTests;
});
```

How can I reset `foo` for each test?

I would like to keep `foo` a revealing module, i.e. not converting it to a constructor function with an altered prototype.

I tried `var foo = require('foo');`, but since requirejs is AMD based, it will complain about things getting loaded in the wrong order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest checking out [SquireJS](https://github.com/iammerrick/Squire.js/) to create an isolated context for your tests.  Squire is designed to inject mock dependencies by creating an isolated RequireJS context.  A side effect of this is that the 'foo' library will be reload each time you call injector.require(), resetting the state of your library.  The only downside is that your tests will need to be asynchronous.

```
// testfoo.js
define(['Squire', 'foo'], function (Squire, foo) {

 'use strict';

  QUnit.start();

  QUnit.module('foo', {
    setup: function () {
    },
    teardown: function () {
    }
  });

  QUnit.test('Testing foo counter in main context.', 2, function (assert) {
    assert.equal(foo.doStuff(), 1); // this will work
    assert.equal(foo.doStuff(), 2); // this should work also.
  });

  QUnit.test('Testing foo counter in context created by Squire.', 1, function (assert) {
    var done = assert.async(),
      injector = new Squire();

    injector.require([
      'foo'
    ], function (foo) {
      assert.equal(foo.doStuff(), 1); // this will work.
      done();
    });

  });

});
```

I've posted a sample project here: [qunit-squirejs](https://github.com/erbronni/qunit-squirejs)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look in to it. Can you please elaborate the downside with "...your tests will need to be asynchronous". Are you implying that the tests can't rely on eachother? If so, I would say that's a good thing, because they shouldn't.

Comment: It is helpful when one module calls another module during initialization, e.g. bar.js -> define(['foo'], function (foo) { foo.doStuff(); }).  If you want foo.doStuff() to return a certain result or throw an exception, you can inject a mock of foo.js using Squire, e..g injector.mock('foo', fooMock).require(['bar'], function (bar) {....})

Answer (score -1):

While this certainly isn't the cleanest way about it, by saving the function as a string, and recreating the function before each test, you can accomplish the same effect.

```
var fooString = foo.toString();
QUnit.testStart(function() { eval('foo = ' + fooString});
```

Comment: While this code fragment might answer the question, it would be more valuable to future readers if you could explain how it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was hoping someone else would give a better answer than this... haha I will update it though